# Validation accuracy stagnates while training accuracy improves

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I'm pretty new to deep learning so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

I am currently training a CNN with a dataset I put together.
When training, the training accuracy behaves pretty normal and improves, reaching >99% accuracy. My validation accuracy starts off at about 75% and fluctuates around 81% ± 1%. After training, the model performs really well on completely new data.

[image: model accuracy]
[image: model loss]

```
Epoch 1/100
187/187 [==============================] - 103s 550ms/step - loss: 1.1336 - acc: 0.5384 - val_loss: 0.8065 - val_acc: 0.7405
Epoch 2/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 519ms/step - loss: 0.8041 - acc: 0.7345 - val_loss: 0.7566 - val_acc: 0.7720
Epoch 3/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 519ms/step - loss: 0.7194 - acc: 0.7945 - val_loss: 0.7410 - val_acc: 0.7846
Epoch 4/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 517ms/step - loss: 0.6688 - acc: 0.8324 - val_loss: 0.7295 - val_acc: 0.7924
Epoch 5/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 518ms/step - loss: 0.6288 - acc: 0.8611 - val_loss: 0.7197 - val_acc: 0.7961
Epoch 6/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 0.5989 - acc: 0.8862 - val_loss: 0.7252 - val_acc: 0.7961
Epoch 7/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 514ms/step - loss: 0.5762 - acc: 0.8981 - val_loss: 0.7135 - val_acc: 0.8063
Epoch 8/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 518ms/step - loss: 0.5513 - acc: 0.9186 - val_loss: 0.7089 - val_acc: 0.8077
Epoch 9/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 513ms/step - loss: 0.5351 - acc: 0.9280 - val_loss: 0.7113 - val_acc: 0.8053
Epoch 10/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 514ms/step - loss: 0.5189 - acc: 0.9417 - val_loss: 0.7167 - val_acc: 0.8094
Epoch 11/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 0.5026 - acc: 0.9483 - val_loss: 0.7104 - val_acc: 0.8162
Epoch 12/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 0.4914 - acc: 0.9538 - val_loss: 0.7114 - val_acc: 0.8101
Epoch 13/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 0.4809 - acc: 0.9583 - val_loss: 0.7099 - val_acc: 0.8141
Epoch 14/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 512ms/step - loss: 0.4681 - acc: 0.9656 - val_loss: 0.7149 - val_acc: 0.8182
Epoch 15/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 0.4605 - acc: 0.9701 - val_loss: 0.7139 - val_acc: 0.8172
Epoch 16/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 514ms/step - loss: 0.4479 - acc: 0.9753 - val_loss: 0.7102 - val_acc: 0.8182
Epoch 17/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 513ms/step - loss: 0.4418 - acc: 0.9805 - val_loss: 0.7087 - val_acc: 0.8247
Epoch 18/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 512ms/step - loss: 0.4363 - acc: 0.9809 - val_loss: 0.7148 - val_acc: 0.8213
Epoch 19/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 516ms/step - loss: 0.4225 - acc: 0.9870 - val_loss: 0.7184 - val_acc: 0.8203
Epoch 20/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 513ms/step - loss: 0.4241 - acc: 0.9863 - val_loss: 0.7216 - val_acc: 0.8189
Epoch 21/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 513ms/step - loss: 0.4132 - acc: 0.9908 - val_loss: 0.7143 - val_acc: 0.8199
Epoch 22/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 0.4050 - acc: 0.9936 - val_loss: 0.7109 - val_acc: 0.8233
Epoch 23/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 515ms/step - loss: 0.4040 - acc: 0.9928 - val_loss: 0.7118 - val_acc: 0.8203
Epoch 24/100
187/187 [==============================] - 96s 511ms/step - loss: 0.3989 - acc: 0.9930 - val_loss: 0.7194 - val_acc: 0.8165
Epoch 25/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 517ms/step - loss: 0.3933 - acc: 0.9946 - val_loss: 0.7163 - val_acc: 0.8155
Epoch 26/100
187/187 [==============================] - 97s 516ms/step - loss: 0.3884 - acc: 0.9957 - val_loss: 0.7225 - val_acc: 0.8148
Epoch 27/100
187/187 [==============================] - 95s 510ms/step - loss: 0.3876 - acc: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.7224 - val_acc: 0.8179
```

The plot in itself looks like overfitting, but I've taken plenty of measures to fix overfitting but none seem to work. Here is my model:

```
# transfer learning with ResNet50
base_model=ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

# function to finetune model
def build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout, fc_layers, num_classes):
    # make base model untrainable
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)

    # add dense layers
    for fc in fc_layers:
        # use regularizer
        x = Dense(fc, use_bias=False, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.003))(x)
        # add batch normalization
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        # add dropout
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    # New softmax layer
    x = Dense(num_classes, use_bias=False)(x) 
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    predictions = Activation('softmax')(x)

    finetune_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    return finetune_model


FC_LAYERS = [1024, 1024]
dropout = 0.5

model = build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout=dropout, fc_layers=FC_LAYERS,num_classes=len(categories))
```

I'm adjusting for class weights and have set a really low learning rate in hopes of slowing the learning down.

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.000005),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'], weighted_metrics=class_weight)
```

I'm really confused by the fact that the validation accuracy starts so high (significantly higher than training accuracy) and barely improves during the entire training process. As mentioned before it seems to be overfitting but I added dropouts, batch normalization and regularizers, it doesn't seem to work. Augmenting data with Horizontal flips, random cropping, random brightness and rotation does not change the accuracy significantly either. Turning shuffle off for my data inside `ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory()` for my training data makes the model train around 25% for training accuracy and <50% for validation accuracy (Edit: accuracy seems to be so low because the learning rate was too low in that case).

Again, the model works surprisingly well on new testing data. I'm looking to increase the validation accuracy and want to understand why the neural network is behaving that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model is overfitting. You may want to use data augmentation on a model of images. e.g. use ImageDataGenerator (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) to randomly shift, rotate and crop images.

SGD tried to find the simplest way possible to minimise the loss function on the dataset; given a large enough set of data points it is forced to come up with a generic solution; but whenever possible DNNs tend to "memorise" the inputs since that is the simplest way to reduce the loss. Dropouts and regularisation do help but at the end of the day what matters is the validation metrics. Assuming of course that your validation set is correctly balanced.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using `horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=[0.9,1], brightness_range=[0.9,1.2], rotation_range=30, fill_mode='constant'` to augment my data. I am using 20% of my data as a validation set, is this what you mean by correctly balanced and should I use augmentation with my validation set as well? Also, is it normal that the validation accuracy is this constant?

Comment: 20% data as validation set is a good ballpark figure. It doesn't make sense to augment the validation data. It is not unusual for a model to overfit like this. You can try to reduce the size of your Dense layers; that may help. Using early stopping when the validation score stops improving is also helpful.